# paginator call on query builder does not return paginator object in laravel 4 (in a specific case)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

#### Problem:

Query builder:

```
$r = DB::table('someTable');
$r->where(....)
$r->paginate(30, array(....))
return $r;
```

Now calling a `get_class()` on `$r` gives `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

But after opening up `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/builder.php`, i saw this,

```
public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = array('*'))
{
    $paginator = $this->connection->getPaginator();


    if (isset($this->groups))
    {
        return $this->groupedPaginate($paginator, $perPage, $columns);
    }
    else
    {            
        return $this->ungroupedPaginate($paginator, $perPage, $columns);
    }
}
```

The line above, `return $this->ungroupedPaginate($paginator, $perPage, $columns);` indeed returns a `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` object.

But after that, it again becomes the *query builder* object.

#### However,

if i do a continuous chain, like below

```
$r = DB::table('someTable')->where(...)->orderBy(....)->paginate(....)
```

It returns a *Paginator* object.

**In both the above two cases**, calling `toSql()` returns the same sql which is being run. So builder is construting the same query only returning different objects in above two cases.

What may be the cause of this? because in my opinion, the resulting object in both the above two cases should be same which is *Paginator*. or am i missing something basic here?

Comment: I hope you realize that the last method you're calling is `paginate` and you wonder why you're getting a paginate object returned...

Comment: @castis no. I am __not__ getting a _Paginator_ object returned and hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-assign the returned value to the `$r` variable.

```
$r = DB::table('someTable');
$r = $r->where(....)
$r = $r->paginate(30, array(....))
return $r;
```