# Laravel 5.3, Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I'm making an attemp to write advanced Eloquent search query filters but when I return the collection to view, I get the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()
```

My Eloquent query builder:

```
$catalogos = Catalogo::query();

$catalogos->where('catalogo.subcategoria',$filtro)
                                ->join('productos', 'productos.catalogo_id','=','catalogo.id')
                                ->join('productos_precios','productos_precios.segment','=','productos.codigo_oracle')
                                ->join('fotos_productos','fotos_productos.producto_id','=','productos.id')
                                ->select('catalogo.descripcion', 'catalogo.descripcion_corta','catalogo.id','fotos_productos.nombre as ruta', 'productos_precios.precio')
                                ->whereNotNull('fotos_productos.nombre')
                                ->orderBy('precio', 'asc')
                                ->groupBy('catalogo.id')
                                ->paginate(24);
```

And yes, if I `dd($catalogos)`, it returns me a Builder instance, but why?

My view code is as follows (just in case you're thinking I'm overwriting the value of the `$catalogos` variable):

```
@foreach($catalogos as $catalogo)   

                            <div class="producto_tienda">
                                <a href="{{route('detalle-producto', [$catalogo->id,$catalogo->slug] ) }}">
                                    <div class="foto_producto" style="background-image:url('{{ asset("public/images/tienda/".$catalogo->ruta) }}')">
                                        @if($catalogo->stock>0 && $catalogo->stock<10)
                                        <div class="etiquetas">
                                            <p class="existencia">Últimos productos</p>
                                        </div>
                                        @endif

                                        @if($catalogo->stock==0)
                                        <div class="etiquetas">
                                            <p class="descuento">Agotado</p>
                                        </div>
                                        @endif

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="{{route('detalle-producto', [$catalogo->id,$catalogo->slug])}}">
                                    <div class="descripcion_producto">{{ $catalogo->descripcion_corta }}</div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="precio_producto">{{ money_format( '%.2n' ,$catalogo->precio) }}</div>

                            </div>



                    @endforeach     
                    <div class="text-center">
                        {{ $catalogos->links() }}
                    </div>
```

Comment: what it shows if you use {{ $catalogos->render() }}

Comment: Is link() a method for class Catalogo?

Comment: @Exprator It shows me a similar error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::render()`

Comment: @Extrakun The method `link()` renders the html buttons for the laravel pagination

Comment: ok just remove the groupby from the query and you are good to go

Comment: @Exprator Still getting the error...

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455712/paginator-call-on-query-builder-does-not-return-paginator-object-in-laravel-4-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it appears to be working with this:

```
$catalogos = Catalogo::query();
$catalogos = $catalogos->where('catalogo.subcategoria',$filtro)
                                    ->join('productos', 'productos.catalogo_id','=','catalogo.id')
                                    ->join('productos_precios','productos_precios.segment','=','productos.codigo_oracle')
                                    ->join('fotos_productos','fotos_productos.producto_id','=','productos.id')
                                    ->select('catalogo.descripcion', 'catalogo.descripcion_corta','catalogo.id','fotos_productos.nombre as ruta', 'productos_precios.precio')
                                    ->whereNotNull('fotos_productos.nombre')
                                    ->orderBy('precio', 'asc')
                                    ->groupBy('catalogo.id')
                                    ->paginate(24);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the return value of `paginate` to anything. It should be:

```
$catalogos = Catalogo::query()->where('catalogo.subcategoria',$filtro)
                            ->join('productos', 'productos.catalogo_id','=','catalogo.id')
                            ->join('productos_precios','productos_precios.segment','=','productos.codigo_oracle')
                            ->join('fotos_productos','fotos_productos.producto_id','=','productos.id')
                            ->select('catalogo.descripcion', 'catalogo.descripcion_corta','catalogo.id','fotos_productos.nombre as ruta', 'productos_precios.precio')
                            ->whereNotNull('fotos_productos.nombre')
                            ->orderBy('precio', 'asc')
                            ->groupBy('catalogo.id')
                            ->paginate(24);
```

Comment: The idea of this, is to apply filters to a query, I can't put all the query at once. I need to begin with `$catalogos = Catalogo::query()` and then add each search parameter as a modifier to the query instance that is returned from `$catalogos = Catalogo::query();`

Comment: The code in your question is functionally identical to this. Either you store the result of `query` in a variable or use it directly it makes no difference. The setters are [fluent](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/03/19/implementing-fluent-interface-pattern-in-php/)

Comment: Hmm I got your point, I solved the problem but I'm concerned about what laravel documentation says about pagination with `groupBy` statement, it is working fine for me right now but I don't know if it would be working fine always...

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez worth looking into but the wording speaks of efficiency so hopefully it will work but will not be the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

You should follow the documentation and create a manual paginator for your query.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator